# Identity using Levi-Civita tensor

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that $\nabla \times (f\nabla g)=\nabla f \times \nabla g$.

So far I have the following:

\begin{align*}
[\nabla \times (f\nabla g)]_i & = \epsilon_{ijk}\,\partial_jf\, \partial_k \,g \\
\end{align*}

I'm not sure where to go from this point, though.

Comment: Product rule.$ $

Comment: @Bye_World Could you explain how to proceed with that in this question please?

Comment: If you apply the product rule to $\partial_j(f\cdot\partial_k g)$ what do you get?

Comment: @Bye_World $ \partial_j f \cdot \partial_k g + f \cdot \partial_j \partial_k g ? $

Comment: Yep.  Now you should recognize that the first term will be your solution.  And so what's left to prove is that the second term (which is the curl of the gradient) is identically zero.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't spot that the second term is just the curl of the gradient .

Comment: No problem. :-)